# limit udp traffic per ip using iptables only

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

i am currently making test udp flood on my ubuntu server as we see in screenshot below

[image]

in this screenshot we see the ip attacker is 162.222.73.109 and this ip is consumed all trafic (100mbps)

my question how can i limit traffic per ip/second ?

i mean if he made udp flood he just get 1 mb/second not full 100mb/second